# Amazon mobile ads interstitial not loading

Tags: mobile, ads, interstitial, amazon-mobile-ads

I am using Amazon Mobile Ads interstitial. I do have `AdRegistration.enableTesting(true);` and `this.interstitialAd.loadAd();`. But when App should show Interstitial Ad, in LogCat i get:

```
07-21 11:21:51.653: W/AmazonMobileAds InterstitialAd(13446): The interstitial ad cannot be shown because it has not loaded successfully. Please call loadAd(AdTargetingOptions) to load an ad first.
```

P.S. When I made it it was working. Two days later when I started the app again, it started showing this warrning.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs, they tell you how to add

```
loadAd(AdTargetingOptions)
```

and you can set the geolocaction tracker (optional)